# Java Applet File Upload Session

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, applet

I have java applet which runs inside the page that has asp.net MVC project. i'll be passing params from asp.net to applet using  tag
function of applet is to search automatically the client side files and do some file processing and list in the jtable. it works absolutely fine when i run the applet in page and open it in a one tab or one window.

issue happens when i run the same applet page in a multiple tabs or multiple windows under the same session. what happens is during file upload it picks value from jtable it is clearing value from all the jtable from different windows / tabs though i was uploading files from one tab / window.

please let me know if you have any ways to fix the same issue.

Comment: *"..let me know if you have any ways to fix the same issue."* Remove all `static` attribute declarations.  If that fails to fix the problem, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Does it clear values from all applet windows or only from applets opened on other tabs/windows ?

Comment: Mohsin -> it clears from all the applet windows that are opened in different tabs and windows running in the same browser.